# Calculating the difference in value between columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with YYYYMM columns that contain monthly totals on the row level:

```
| yearM | feature  | 201902 | 201903 | 201904 | 201905 |... ... ... 202009
|-------|----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 0     | feature1 | Nan    | Nan    | 9.0    | 32.0   |
| 1     | feature2 | 1.0    | 1.0    | 1.0    | 4.0    |
| 2     | feature3 | Nan    | 1.0    | 4.0    | 8.0    |
| 3     | feature4 | 9.0    | 15.0   | 19.0   | 24.0   |
| 4     | feature5 | 33.0   | 67.0   | 99.0   | 121.0  |
| 5     | feature6 | 12.0   | 15.0   | 17.0   | 19.0   |
| 6     | feature7 | 1.0    | 8.0    | 15.0   | 20.0   |
| 7     | feature8 | Nan    | Nan    | 1.0    | 9.0    |
```

I would like to convert the totals to the monthly change. The `feature` column should be excluded as I need to keep the feature names. The `yearM` in the index is a result of pivoting a dataframe to get the YYYYMM on the column level.

This is how the output would look like:

```
| yearM | feature  | 201902 | 201903 | 201904 | 201905 |... ... ... 202009
|-------|----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 0     | feature1 | Nan    | 0.0    | 9.0    | 23.0   |
| 1     | feature2 | 1.0    | 0.0    | 0.0    | 3.0    |
| 2     | feature3 | Nan    | 1.0    | 3.0    | 5.0    |
| 3     | feature4 | 9.0    | 6.0    | 4.0    | 5      |
| 4     | feature5 | 33.0   | 34.0   | 32.0   | 22.0   |
| 5     | feature6 | 12.0   | 3.0    | 2.0    | 2.0    |
| 6     | feature7 | 1.0    | 7.0    | 7.0    | 5.0    |
| 7     | feature8 | Nan    | 0.0    | 1.0    | 8.0    |
```

The row level values now represent the change compared to the previous month instead of having the total for the month.

I know that I should start by filling the `NaN` rows in the starting column `201902` with 0:

```
df['201902'] = df['201902'].fillna(0)
```

I could also calculate them one by one with something similar to this:

```
df['201902'] = df['201902'].fillna(0) - df['201901'].fillna(0)
df['201903'] = df['201903'].fillna(0) - df['201902'].fillna(0)
df['201904'] = df['201904'].fillna(0) - df['201903'].fillna(0)
...
...
```

Hopefully there's a smarter solution though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `iloc` or `drop` to access the other columns, then `diff` with `axis=1` for row-wise differences.

```
monthly_change = df.iloc[:, 1:].fillna(0).diff(axis=1)
# or
# monthly_change = df.drop(['feature'], axis=1).fillna(0).diff(axis=1)
```

Comment: I seem to get a syntax error on the first `:` in the `iloc`

Comment: Runs fine on my system. What exactly does the error say?

Comment: Oh I mistyped and used () instead of []

Comment: Yep, just saw that! So the calculation seems correct in terms of the monthly difference, though I do lose the `feature` column which I need to retain

Comment: It's just one column, you can assign back `monthly_change['feature'] = df['feature']` :-)